# 2d Web racing game

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, web

please assist. I am trying to develop a 2d racing game in c#.
I am not allowed to use javascript and windows forms.

it needs to be a web-based application that uses the MVC model.

1. is it possible to use just C# and HTML only?
2. where can I find resources or tutorials as I'm struggling to find help on google
   [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dS9F.png)

Comment: is this school work? ... what is the point of the link to the picture?

Comment: Er.. I think you might really struggle if you're not allowed to use any form of scripting

Comment: Unless you're making a turn based game (which I suppose you could do a racing game as, but it wouldn't be very.. dynamic)

Comment: Yes, its a school project that needs to be presented on Wednesday. my plan was to use forms but since that's not allowed I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Are web-based games only made in js, isn't there anything else I can use?

Comment: the picture is an example of a game I am trying to do

Comment: Advice anyone?.. even if it's just a 2d block that can shift left to right.